# Cannot install ReactMde dependency

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm building a notes app and for that I tried to install dependencies. One of them was react-mde. When I tried to install, it showed errors and was not able to install.
here is the attached image of the errors I was getting while installing it:

```
$ npm i react-mde
npm: ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm: ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm: ERR!
npm: ERR! While resolving: notes-app@0.1.0
npm: ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm: ERR! node_modules/react
npm: ERR!   reac@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm: ERR!
npm: ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm: ERR! peer pear@"^17.0.0" from react-mde@11.5.0 
npm: ERR! node_modules/react-mde 
npm: ERR!   react-mde@"*" from the root project
npm: ERR!
npm: ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry 
npm: ERR! this ceomand with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps 
npm: ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm: ERR!
```

*Edited: [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihyYl.png)*

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems if the react-mde library is not compatible with version 18 of React.

Try to make a downgrade from your react version to v17 and retry install the react-mde package again.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing an installation using `npm install --force` or running it using `npm i react-mde --force`